# How to avoid customer's order history being changed in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections

1. Customers
2. Products

I have a field called "orders" in each of my customer document and what this "orders" field does is that it stores a reference to the product Id which was ordered by a customer, now my question is since I'm referencing product Id and if I update the "title" of that product then it will also update in the customer's order history since I can't embed each order information since a customer may order thousands of products and it can hit 16mb mark in no time so what's the fix for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Orders Collection

1. Store ID of the user who made the order
2. Store ID of the product bought

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I can do that but the problem will be still there since I'm storing product ID then if I change the price of that product it will then be updated too in customer's order history and for obvious reasons we don't want to change the price of the product after the customer orders it even if we do we don't want to reflect those changes in the customer's order history.

Comment: If that's the case, in addition to what i said:
Store the price of the product  at that point in time in the order collection.
The Order collection would contain these essential keys:
owerID, createdAt, updatedAt, amount, orderID, productID

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are looking up the value of the product from the customer entity. You will always get the latest price if you are not storing the order/price historical transactions. Because your data model is designed this way to retrieve the latest price information.
My suggestion.
Orders place with product and price always need to be stored in history entity or like order lines and not allow any process to change it so that when you look up products that customers brought you can always get the historical price and price change of the product should not affect the previous order. Two options.

1. Store the order history in the current collection customers (or top say 50 order lines if you don't need all of history(write additional logic to handle this)
2. if "option1" is not feasible due to large no. of orders think of creating an order lines transaction table and refer order line for the product brought via DBref or lookup command.
   Note: it would have helped if you have given no. of transactions in each collection currently and its expected rate of growth of documents in the collection QoQ.

Answer (score 0):

You have orders and products. Orders are referencing products. Your problem is that the products get updated and now your orders reference the new product. The easiest way to combat this issue is to store full data in each order. Store all the key product-related information.

The advantage is that this kind of solution is extremely easy to visualize and implement. The disadvantage is that you have a lot of repetitive data since most of your products probably don't get updated.

If you store a product update history based on timestamps, then you could solve your problem. Products are identified now by 3 fields. The product ID, active start date and active end date. Or you could configure products in this way: product ID = product ID + "Version X" and store this version against each order.

If you use dates, then you will query for the product and find the product version that was active during the time period that the order occurred. If you use versions against the product, then you will simply query the database for the particular version of the product itself. I haven't used mongoDb so I'm not sure how you would achieve this in mongoDb exactly. Naively however, you can modify the product ID to include the version as well using # as a delimiter possibly.

The advantage of this solution is that you don't store too much of extra data. Considering that products won't be updated too often, I feel like this is the ideal solution to your problem